# Trucrypt and remote access - how to?

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop, encryption, truecrypt

I have encrypted whole system partition drive via truecrypt but now I can't remote access my computer. I need to be physically be in front of computer, to enter password.

Is there possible to enter password from remote computer via SSH ? I mean, I know it is, but first off course I need enter to the system (win7) and then I can connect via VNC/remote access and then eventually give password to truecrypt to decrypt files. But how to enter to the system when I need give truecrypt a pass first...

Any idea on this ?

Comment: with a ip kvm it's possible.

Comment: or Intel ATM

http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/intel-active-management-technology.html

Comment: The Truecrypt bootloader runs before the OS is loaded - so direct SSH access to it is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, not unless your setup includes some form of [Out-Of-Band Management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-band_management), as the password prompt appears before the OS is loaded.

As folks have suggested in the comments, you'd need something like an [IP KVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch#KVM_over_IP_.28IPKVM.29), or a computer that includes something like [Intel's AMT/vPro](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/intel-active-management-technology.html), or [HP's ILO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_Integrated_Lights-Out), [Dell's DRAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dell_DRAC), etc.

Answer (score 0):

This would be very difficult to achive because you need a system to remote connect to... Truecrypt bootloader starts before the OS. However, if this is a server like environment where you do not physically use the computer, you could partition the drive and run windows on one partition and store all your files on a seperate partition, then encrypt only the storage partition, at which point windows would boot normally and you can remote connect to it. The only other option i see is to run the OS virtually on top of another os, so that you could remote connect to the host and control the virtual os... something like a small/light linux distro and windows on top...

Answer (score -1):

Nah... it's way more simpler. You dont need special hardware pieces - http://www.howtoforge.com/unlock-a-luks-encrypted-root-partition-via-ssh-on-ubuntu

I have read that you don't even need a second system - you just encrypt piece of partition and then decrypt it when system is loaded.

Thanks for comments!

Comment: That's for LUKS, not Truecrypt FDE.